# Autocomplete customize it - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, autocomplete, customization

Before I start the question, I know that some of you won't read the question carefully and will think that I'm asking for something as simple as `addClass("custom1")` to my original `#elem`, like this:

```
$("#elem1").autocomplete("source1.php").addClass("custom1");
```

**This won't do it**, because I'm not trying to add the class to my target div... I'm trying to add it to the dynamically-generated div that the plugin generates.

**Now to my question :)** thanks in advance

I have several autocompletes like this:

```
$("#elem1").autocomplete("source1.php"); 
$("#elem2").autocomplete("source2.php");
$("#elem3").autocomplete("source3.php");
```

By default, the results for each one are returned in a separate div class called `.ac_results` that gets added before the body close.

```
   <div class="ac_results" style="display: none;">
      <ul style="overflow: auto; max-height: 180px;">
        //the results here as li's.. they vary with what you typed
      </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="ac_results" style="display: none;">
      <ul style="overflow: auto; max-height: 180px;">
        //**THESE LIs ARE DIFFERENT FROM THE SET ABOVE**
      </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="ac_results" style="display: none;">
      <ul style="overflow: auto; max-height: 180px;">
        //**THESE LIs ARE EVEN DIFFERENT FROM THE 2 SETS ABOVE**
      </ul>
   </div>
</body>
```

I have a custom class though **for each `#elem`** that I need to add to the divs that the plugin dynamically generates, to make the end result look like this: (the only change is I added `custom1 custom2 custom3` classes)

```
   <div class="ac_results custom1" style="display: none;">
      <ul style="overflow: auto; max-height: 180px;">
        //the results here as li's.. they vary with what you typed
      </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="ac_results custom2" style="display: none;">
      <ul style="overflow: auto; max-height: 180px;">
        //**THESE LIs ARE DIFFERENT FROM THE SET ABOVE**
      </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="ac_results custom3" style="display: none;">
      <ul style="overflow: auto; max-height: 180px;">
        //**THESE LIs ARE EVEN DIFFERENT FROM THE 2 SETS ABOVE**
      </ul>
   </div>
</body>
```

so I need to either:

- somehow wipe off the default .ac_results completely and replace it with my own classes (different class for each elem) at each .autocomplete() declareation
- or keep the `ac_results` and add my custom classes (different for each autocomplete) after it's rendered

The problem:

- The html divs the plugin generates all look the same. You can't tell the difference short of examining the content of the li's.
- The html divs get generated only **after** you start typing into the autocomplete for that #elem, **AND** whichever gets used last, gets added to the DOM last before the body close.

  - **This means I can't use DOM order to map them**.
  - At first-render of html, the DOM will not have any `div class="ac_results"`. If `#elem3` was used, one `div class="ac_results"` gets added for it. If `#elem1` was used after, another `div class="ac_results"` gets added for it, so the div for `elem1` is actually after the div for `elem3`, hence what I said about not being able to use order.

**Some extra info**

I'm using JQuery Autocomplete 1.1. This link from the jquery issues is a very close file, although not identical http://plugins.jquery.com/files/issues/jquery.autocomplete.js__0.txt.

From the file, I have on my HDD, here's some of the code. I removed most of the lines that aren't important. The most important is `resultsClass: "ac_results"`, that's the class of the div that gets auto-generated.

```
   $.Autocompleter.defaults = {
        inputClass: "ac_input",
        resultsClass: "ac_results",
        loadingClass: "ac_loading",
        extraParams: {},
    };
```

The resultClass then gets used later on in a function init(), I'm displaying this intact without removing any lines just in case. **Ideally what I want to do is make init accept an extra class.**

```
// Create results
function init() {
    if (!needsInit)
        return;
    element = $("<div/>")
    .hide()
    .addClass(options.resultsClass)
    .css("position", "absolute")
    .appendTo(document.body);

    list = $("<ul/>").appendTo(element).mouseover( function(event) {
        if(target(event).nodeName && target(event).nodeName.toUpperCase() == 'LI') {
            active = $("li", list).removeClass(CLASSES.ACTIVE).index(target(event));
            $(target(event)).addClass(CLASSES.ACTIVE);            
        }
    }).click(function(event) {
        $(target(event)).addClass(CLASSES.ACTIVE);
        select();
        // TODO provide option to avoid setting focus again after selection? useful for cleanup-on-focus
        input.focus();
        return false;
    }).mousedown(function() {
        config.mouseDownOnSelect = true;
    }).mouseup(function() {
        config.mouseDownOnSelect = false;
    });

    if( options.width > 0 )
        element.css("width", options.width);

    needsInit = false;
}
```

Comment: does the CSS class that you need to add correspond to the `#elem` that is used to generate the results?

Comment: It can be made to correspond if need be. I could split the name or something to get -number like -1-2 3 etc. You have an idea? we can discuss

Comment: Yeah, I think I do, if I've understood your requirement correctly. Let me clarify - when the autocomplete finishes (i.e. the user is not still searching/typing), a `<div>` result with matches is appended to the end of the body. the requirement is to be able to add a CSS class to that generated `<div>` in order to identify it in some way. Is this correct?

Comment: could you alter the js source so that the elements are prepared and made invisible at document ready for each ac you call?

Comment: how are the results of the autocomplete being put into the `<ul>`? Can we see the code for that?

Comment: @Russ, that's exactly my goal. The plugin uses ajax anyway (just like the tags here on SO, with every stroke it queries the server and changes the suggestions/li's). So even at the first keystroke, that div would be born.. and you're exactly right, I want to add the css class to it to identify it (for custom styling actually)

Comment: @tharkun, I get your point, but the plugin will generate its own anyway as the autocomplete input gets typed into, and I'm guessing it won't recognize that I generated it for it. I think better to work with what the plugin generates.

Comment: @Russ, I'm using JQuery Autocomplete 1.1.. will update the post to include some of its code, but I believe this link from the jquery issues is a very close file, although not identical 
http://plugins.jquery.com/files/issues/jquery.autocomplete.js__0.txt

Comment: I meant you to change the plugin!

Comment: @tharkun, I agree, as a user, I agree the plugin could use some improvements, but since I'm not the one who coded and I'm not even an intermediate jquery, I wouldn't want to mess with it myself ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the autocomplete plugin, the passed in options are merged with the defaults using `$.extend`. Here is the code

```
autocomplete: function(urlOrData, options) {
        var isUrl = typeof urlOrData == "string";
        options = $.extend({}, $.Autocompleter.defaults, {
            url: isUrl ? urlOrData : null,
            data: isUrl ? null : urlOrData,
            delay: isUrl ? $.Autocompleter.defaults.delay : 10,
            max: options && !options.scroll ? 10 : 150
        }, options);
```

and here are the defaults

```
$.Autocompleter.defaults = {
    inputClass: "ac_input",
    resultsClass: "ac_results",
    loadingClass: "ac_loading",
    minChars: 1,
    delay: 400,
    matchCase: false,
    matchSubset: true,
    matchContains: false,
    cacheLength: 10,
    max: 100,
    mustMatch: false,
    extraParams: {},
    selectFirst: true,
    formatItem: function(row) { return row[0]; },
    formatMatch: null,
    autoFill: false,
    width: 0,
    multiple: false,
    multipleSeparator: ", ",
    highlight: function(value, term) {
        return value.replace(new RegExp("(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" + term.replace(/([\^\$\(\)\[\]\{\}\*\.\+\?\|\\])/gi, "\\$1") + ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"), "<strong>$1</strong>");
    },
    scroll: true,
    scrollHeight: 180
};
```

Since the CSS class used for the results `<div>` is not protected inside of the defaults, all we need do is pass in our own CSS class to use for the results `<div>`. Something like the following

```
var id = $("#elem1").attr('id');   
$("#elem1")
    .autocomplete("source1.php", {resultsClass: "ac_results " +id});
```

You'll just need to set the appropriate id to use in the resultsClass CSS class for each autocomplete.

Comment: the key is that the passed in `options` object is added last in the `$.extend`, meaning that properties specified in this object will override the properties in previous objects (i.e. the `$.Autocompleter.defaults` object)